# option button in selected mode in vba access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox, radio-button, ms-access-2010

I have a check box in a access form and i want when this check box selected , a option button in my form becomes selected.

Sorry, I know this is a amateur question but i need an answer. I used this but it doesn't work :

`If (Me.Check86 = True) Then
    Option107.OptionValue = 1
Else
    Option110.OptionValue = 0
End If`

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Comment: I see you have a couple of open questions. If the answers provided helped you please consider [accepting them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  This rewards the contributor and helps others with the same problem to find a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd7e4yte(v=vs.90).aspx) instead.

[OptionValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191808.aspx) is used when several option buttons are grouped together.  It allows you to determine which of the option buttons has been selected.

**Example**

```
Private Sub Check86_Click()
' Update option buttons based on value of checkbox.

    Option107.Value = Me.Check86.Value      ' Sync check box and option.
    Option110.Value = Not Option107.Value   ' Ensures only one option button is selected at a time.
End Sub
```

This [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh211482(v=office.14).aspx) is fired each time the check box is checked/unchecked.  It checks/unchecks `Option107` to match.  It then sets `Option110` to the reverse setting. I'm assuming you only want one option button checked at a time.

I've used the [not operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278748.aspx) to ensure `Option110` and `Check86` hold different values.  When `Check86` is true `Option110` is not true, ie false.

Comment: Thanks, but access don't let me use 'value' property for option button like this.

Comment: Hhhmm.  I tested this on MSAccess 2010 yesterday.  We should be able to get it working for you.  What error message did Access return?  Are your option buttons bound to a data field?  Are your option buttons in a group?